# Is Aliasing works for Quickbooks sdk?

Tags: java, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am Working on fetching data from quickbooks SDK through JAVA.
I am able to run these type of queries

select * from invoice.

select * from invoice where id =1;

but when i am using aliases 'as'

select id as myid from invoice.

it is throwing below error

Exception in thread "main" com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException: ERROR CODE:4000, ERROR MESSAGE:Error parsing query, ERROR DETAIL:QueryParserError: Encountered " "as" "as "" at line 1, column 11.
Was expecting one of:

"," ...
".*" ...
"from" ...
"iterator" ...
"maxresults" ...
"order" ...
"orderby" ...
"startposition" ...
"where" ..

IS there any alternative query so that i can uses aliasing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid syntax is described in the docs here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/data-queries

Aliasing (e.g. use of the `AS` keyword) is *not* supported.